# Specifying a Many-to-many that handles two join tables (that previously handled many-to-manys) w/ entity framework core

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have never been in the situation where I originally had two many-to-many's that were resolved. But then down another level is another many-to-many on both of those join tables. I am wondering if there is a better way to architect this w/ entity framework core. Here is what I got. I am trying to figure out which Project Owners are part of which Project Products.

I have 3 tables:

Project
Product
Owner

A Project can have many Products and a Project can have many Owners. A Product can have many Projects and an Owner can have many Projects. I resolved these two many-to-many relationships by doing the following:

**ProjectProduct**
Two keys: ProjectId, ProductId

**ProjectOwner**
Two keys: ProjectId, OwnerId

Additionally a ProjectProduct can have many ProjectOwners and a ProjectOwner can have many ProjectsProducts.

I thought the solution would be to add a unique Id to both ProjectOwner and ProjectProduct and create a new entity called **ProjectProductOwner** with the following keys:
ProjectProductId, ProjectOwnerId

Here is what my DBContext looks like:

```
// Key Specifications
modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectProductOwner>()
    .HasKey(x => new { x.ProjectProductId, x.ProjectOwnerId });

// Project Product
modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectProduct>()
    .HasOne(x => x.Project)
    .WithMany(x => x.Products)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.ProjectId);

modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectProduct>()
    .HasOne(x => x.Product)
    .WithMany(x => x.Projects)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.ProductId);

// Project Owner
modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectOwner>()
    .HasOne(x => x.Project)
    .WithMany(x => x.Owners)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.ProjectId);

modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectOwner>()
    .HasOne(x => x.Owner)
    .WithMany(x => Projects)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.OwnerId);

// Project Product Owner
modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectProductOwner>()
    .HasOne(x => x.ProjectProduct)
    .WithMany(x => x.ProjectOwners)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.ProjectProductId);

modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectProductOwner>()
    .HasOne(x => x.ProjectOwner)
    .WithMany(x => x.ProjectProducts)
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.ProjectOwnerId);
```

I am getting the error:
Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_ProjectProductOwner_ProjectProducts_ProjectProductId' on table 'ProjectProductOwner' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths.

additionally:

'FK_ProjectProductOwner_ProjectOwners_ProjectOwnerId' on table 'ProjectProductOwner' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths.

Comment: Why do you need ProjectProductOwner? If you have already a relation between Owner and Project and anotger one between Project and Product I think is enough. If you need Owner Products you just go via Projects.

Comment: @LucianBumb hmm what do you mean just go via projects. Can you elaborate on that. I had a feeling what I was doing was overkill. The order that all of this happens is the following: Owners are added to the Project then a Product is added to the Project along with many Owners (limited to the ones added to the Project earlier). Then another Product can get added to the Project along with one-to-many Owners (limited to the Project owners) again.

Comment: I am trying to figure out how to store which Project Owners are part of which Project Products.

Comment: Why does adding products also adds more owners? Does this mean that first you need to add `Owners` to the project, so you can only add products that are "owned" by the already added owners of the project? Also: Is this a new database or something that already exists?

Comment: @jpgrassi It is a completely new database using EF Core to create it w/ migrations. The order that things are going to happen on the UI is the following. Owners and Products are both configurations in the system. A Project is created by the user. Then a user picks from a multi select many Owners to be part of the Project. Then further down the line a User adds a single Product at a time to the Project but needs to assign which ProjectOwners are managing that Product. The last part is what is messing me all up.

Comment: @jpgrassi Correct, both Products and Owners are stand-alone in the domain prior to a Project being created. Since a Project has many Owners and an Owner in the system can be part of many projects. When an Owner logs in I would need to show the Projects they are part of at some point so a nav property would be nice. This would make it a many-to-many. Let's say we did go with adding two one-to-manys for Project:Owner and Project:Product I don't see how I would be able to say which Owners are part of which Products within the Project and be able to query it when editing.

Comment: @jpgrassi please read my above comment as well. Do you see why I have two many to manys at first? One for Project:Owners and one for Project:Products. Then I would need to be to say which Project:Owners are part of which Project:Products. Wouldn't this requires yet again another many-to-many?

Comment: No sorry, I had things mixed up. Now it's more clear what you want. But I still can't understand the Owners > Product part.

Comment: @jpgrassi Owners are added to the Project before anything, being pulled from Owners config. Then a Product gets added to the Project using a select list that is populated from the Products config. Then there is a picker of all the Owners that were added to the Project in a previous step. Let's say Owner 1 and Owner 2 are selected. Then the user can click Add Another Product. Once again select from the list of Product Config, then select from a list of the Project Owners which person(s) will own the Product. This time let's say it's Owner1 and Owner3.

Comment: @jpgrassi In my above example we would have a Project w/ Owner1, Owner2 and Owner3 from config setup in Wizard step 1. Then in wizard step 2 (Add Products) A Project:Product1 w/ Owner1 and Owner2 set as the managers. Then a Project:Product2 w/ Owner1 and Owner3 set as the managers

Comment: Okay now it makes sense :). This fired my curiosity so I'll try to come up with something.

Comment: @jpgrassi I appreciate it, I don't know why I am struggling so hard with this. 1. I want to make sure I'm not overthinking it with all of these many-to-manys. 2. I want to know if those Cascade delete error messages mean I came up with a bad design (which they usually do). Or is it as simple as keeping my current design and disabling Cascade delete. Please see in my post how I am telling EF about all of this using fluent API. I handled the many-to-manys exactly as instructed by the EF Core documentation. Just never did a many to many within a many to many before so it seems wrong.

Comment: @jpgrassi My entities are as follows: Project, Product, Owner (only 3 entities specified as Dbsets since I should be able to do everything through them). Then there is ProjectOwner used to resolve many to many. Then there is ProjectProduct used to resolve the many to many. Then there needs to be ProjectProductOwner to resolve the many-to-many within the Project saying which ProjectOwners will be managing which ProjectProducts within the Project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188208/discussion-between-jpgrassi-and-blake-rivell).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can "merge" the `ProjectProduct` with the `ProjectProductOwner` into one table. Since you add `Owners` to the `Project` first, then you add one or more `Products` for each `Owner` in the `Project` I don't see a need for a third many-to-many Entity, thus simplifying it a bit :)

Note: I didn't even bother with the error, because as you said and I agree, most often these errors show up when your model isn't correct.

`Owner`

```
public class Owner
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProjectOwner> ProjectOwners { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProjectProductOwner> ProjectProductOwners { get; set; }
}
```

`Product`

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProjectProductOwner> ProjectProductOwners { get; set; }
}
```

`Project and many-to-many tables`

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProjectOwner> ProjectOwners { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ProjectProductOwner> ProjectProductOwners { get; set; }

    public Project()
    {
        ProjectOwners = new List<ProjectOwner>();
        ProjectProductOwners = new List<ProjectProductOwner>();
    }
}

public class ProjectOwner
{
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }
    public Owner Owner { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectProductOwner
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }
    public Owner Owner { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

`DbContext` configuration

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    // Configure Owners in a Project
    modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectOwner>()
        .HasKey(p => new { p.ProjectId, p.OwnerId });

    modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectOwner>()
        .HasOne(bc => bc.Project)
        .WithMany(b => b.ProjectOwners)
        .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.ProjectId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectOwner>()
        .HasOne(bc => bc.Owner)
        .WithMany(c => c.ProjectOwners)
        .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.OwnerId);

    // Configure Products for each owner in a Project
    modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectProductOwner>()
        .HasKey(p => new { p.ProjectId, p.ProductId, p.OwnerId });

    modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectProductOwner>()
        .HasOne(bc => bc.Project)
        .WithMany(b => b.ProjectProductOwners)
        .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.ProjectId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectProductOwner>()
        .HasOne(bc => bc.Product)
        .WithMany(c => c.ProjectProductOwners)
        .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.ProductId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<ProjectProductOwner>()
        .HasOne(bc => bc.Owner)
        .WithMany(c => c.ProjectProductOwners)
        .HasForeignKey(bc => bc.OwnerId);
}
```

Finally, you can add new projects and query it with something like this:

```
using (var db = new ProjectContext())
{
    var project = new Project();
    project.Name = "My project";

    // assumes there's 3 owners and 2 products already inserted in the DB

    // Add the 3 owners to the project
    project.ProjectOwners.Add(new ProjectOwner { OwnerId = 1});
    project.ProjectOwners.Add(new ProjectOwner { OwnerId = 2});
    project.ProjectOwners.Add(new ProjectOwner { OwnerId = 3});

    // Add Product 1 to Owner 1 and 2
    project.ProjectProductOwners.Add(new ProjectProductOwner { ProductId = 1, OwnerId = 1 });
    project.ProjectProductOwners.Add(new ProjectProductOwner { ProductId = 1, OwnerId = 2 });

    // Add Product 2 to Owner 1 and 3
    project.ProjectProductOwners.Add(new ProjectProductOwner { ProductId = 2, OwnerId = 1 });
    project.ProjectProductOwners.Add(new ProjectProductOwner { ProductId = 2, OwnerId = 3 });

    db.Add(project);
    db.SaveChanges();

    var projects = db.Project
        .Include(p => p.ProjectOwners)
        .ThenInclude(p => p.Owner)
        .Include(p => p.ProjectProductOwners)
        .ThenInclude(p => p.Product)
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Just realized I was thinking about this in the wrong way. Product is actually ProductType. A Project/ProductType/Owner combination isn't always truly unique. There is the rare case that the user can do the following: Within Project1, select ProductType1, select Owner1. Then when adding another combination within Project1 the user selects ProductType1 again, and then selects Owner1 and Owner2. In this case we would have duplicate keys for (Project1.Id/ProductType1.Id/Owner1.Id). Any idea how I can adjust this architecture so this scenario can be handled?

Comment: But ProductType1 + Owner1 already exists so you just add ProductType1 + Owner2. No need to create another row for Project1 + ProductType1 + Owner1. You could either check before saving or not even allowing to select Owner1 if that combination is already present :)

Comment: For instance, when displaying the "dialog" to select the owners after selecting a `ProductType` you could run a query on `Owners` where OwnerId does not exist on `ProjectProductOwners` (meaning, only return the Owners that were not yet assigned for this project and this producttype)

Comment: What I am saying is that through the UI the user can add the same exact combination. Maybe I should just tell you my real entities instead of using these dummy entities for the example. It is Loan, Borrower, CollateralType. Two borrowers get added to a loan. Then on the next screen the user selects a CollateralType (i.e. Car) and then associates it with borrower(s). Then the user can select another collateral type (could be the same one) and then associates it with borrower(s) (could be the same borrower(s) from the first one) if the Borrower owns two cars they want to collateralize.

Comment: I think I got it the first time hehe. Anyway, unless you need to actually count if Borrower1 was added twice for CollateralType1, it doesn't make a difference adding it twice, or? Is CollateralType the same Id in both cases? I guess this is the part which you need to figure it out. If it's the same (like an enum table) then it doesn't make sense to add it twice.

Comment: I will need to list it twice because technically it needs to show as two line items:  So in an extreme scenario you could end up with: Loan1/Borrower1/Car, Loan1/Borrower1/Car, Loan1/Borrower1/House, Loan1/Borrower1/House, Loan1/Borrower2/House. I would need to list the following: Here is the collateral for the loan: Car - Borrower1, Car - Borrower1, House - Borrower1, House - Borrower1, Borrower2 (in the event they own the same house together).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188524/discussion-between-jpgrassi-and-blake-rivell).